# Python invoke: Get the flags from a parent command?

Tags: pyinvoke

Given the following python [invoke](https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/index.html) script:

```py
from invoke import task

@task
def pre(c):
   print("pre")

@task(pre=[pre])
def command(c, flag):
   print(f"command flag={flag}")
```

Called with the following shell command:

`inv command --flag`

I would like to read the value of `flag` to conditionally do some actions in `pre`. Is there a way I can read the `flag` property passed to `command` from within `pre` using invoke's API? I couldn't find anything in the docs about it.

I am aware that push comes to shove, I can import sys and read the args directly, but I'd rather avoid doing that work manually if I can.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through a few GH issues, I found that the feature has yet to be implemented at this point in time.

Discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/229), and a PR for a similar feature can be found [here](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/pull/730).

The proposed solution in the first discussion is to call the pre/post task directly in the main task:

```py
@task
def pre(c, flag):
   print("pre")

@task
def command(c, flag):
   pre(c, flag)
   print(f"command flag={flag}")
```